# Is there any option to make this application on middle of the page?

Tags: css

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

New to Bulma Framework and would like to put this application on the center of the webpage. May I ask please how to achieve it?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TKQe.jpg

Comment: DId you try margin or padding ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `margin-left: *value*;` in your CSS.

Example: `body {margin-left: 33.33%;}`